# Delegate loosing View Controller objects swift

Tags: ios, swift

All,

I have set up a protocol, and the view controller is the delegate of this protocol, like so :

```
import Foundation

protocol PayButtonProtocol {
    func enablePayButton()
    func disablePayButton()
}
```

And the view controller is the delegate :

```
class ViewController:   UIViewController, PayButtonProtocol
```

The protocol functions are as follows :

```
func enablePayButton() {
        println("Button enabled")
        PAYBarButton.enabled = false
    }

    func disablePayButton() {
        PAYBarButton.enabled = false
    }
```

I set a class and assign the delegate :

```
class Trigger
{
    var delegate:PayButtonProtocol?

    func EnablePayButton()
    {
        delegate?.enablePayButton()
    }
}
```

Then I set the trigger to run the function :

```
let localtrigger = Trigger()
        localtrigger.delegate = ViewController()
        localtrigger.EnablePayButton()
```

This works and the 'button enabled' is displayed in the console. But the Bar Button (PAYBarButton) is nil and it seems that the view controller has lost its hieracy as I cannot access any of the view controllers objects. The View Controller was built with interface builder. Anyone got any ideas ? Is it

```
localtrigger.delegate = ViewController()
```

that rebuilds the viewconotroller and makes the original one not accessible ? If so how do i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating the `localTrigger` object inside your `ViewController` class you can just do:

```
let localtrigger = Trigger()
localtrigger.delegate = self // self is an instance of ViewController
localtrigger.EnablePayButton()
```